# How to scale down a sprite based on the screen size

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a 2D tower defense game I'm making and I want to scale down the towers to match the size of a tile. So I do:

```
public static tile = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 24;
```

To get the size of a tile and then

```
float scale = tile / 80;
```

To get the scale however when I run the game only a sliver of the sprite is drawn. What am I doing wrong?
Code where i draw the sprite:

```
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, center, null, Color.White, rotation,
    origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article on Scaling Sprites Based On Screen Size.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447674.aspx

Also read more about the preferredbackbufferwidth:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.preferredbackbufferwidth.aspx

If u want to know all overloads, read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx